# Is there any tools for me to inspect which code is being ran?

Tags: webos, code-inspection

I wanna to play around the HP webOS, and doing something system level modification. As you may know that the webOS can inspect the source code, and digging inside the system with something like WebOS doctor with ssh. But I would like to inspect when I doing something, which lines of code is being execute, or.... at least which file is being execute, any ideas on that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Ares debugger - https://ares.palm.com/Ares/docstemp/debug.html

Or if you are developing in Enyo - you can use the Javascript debugger to set watches and breaks in your code. CTRL+SHIFT+J on a windows machine will bring that up.

Comment: Here are the links to Ares - https://ares.palm.com/AresDebug and  https://ares.palm.com/AresLog - use with the SDK and emulator or device and usb cable.